# Infinispan file system store plus sql database

Tags: infinispan

I am trying to use infinispan to achieve the following:
-   n JVM instances in cluster
-   All data replicated between one node and the remaining nodes
-   Data to be backed up by the filesystem to that the node can recover from the local file store
-   I want some specific data to be persisted in the database (sql) asynchronously, but first to be written on the filesystem synchronously and once the transaction has been committed – then trigger the asynchronous persistence to the sql database

What is unclear from the documentation, it seems I will have to do everything myself – and infinispan just gives me jgroups clustering
It is unclear also how to remove data from the file store once the sql persistence successfully takes place – within an “atomic” transaction.

So data replication aside, I must be able to:

- Store data to the local cache (in-memory and file-system)
- Recover from the local cache (if the JVM crashes) and/or remote caches
- For some data, add to the cache, then FS, then asynchronously persist and remove from the FS

It seems that I can do all of this obviously, but Infinispan vs. me using jgroups and do it myself?

Answer (score 0):

Infinispan allows you to chain cache stores together (by defining multiple stores within the persistence XML section), and each can be configured to either be synchronous or asynchronous (see [here](http://infinispan.org/docs/8.1.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_write_through_and_write_behind_caching)). However, transactional persistence stores are not supported (see [here](http://infinispan.org/docs/8.1.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_cache_loaders_and_transactional_caches))